# Mobile Framework for Meteor Mobile Web App

Tags: jquery-mobile, meteor

I'm new to Meteor and loving it but I'm having a hard time figuring out an ideal mobile framework to use for Mobile Web Apps, not native or hybrid strictly Mobile Web App (HTML5, CSS, Javascript) initially. Down the road I will create native versions with phonegap or native sdk.

Currently I've been using Bootstrap to make my apps responsive but ideally I'd like to use JQ Mobile for listviews, sliders, theming and other things.

I get the feeling that the main issue is the JQM Ajax Navigation and some DOM issues.

Any suggestions would be great, jQuery Mobile would be ideal but I get the feeling it doesn't play well with Meteor.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by framework? is meteor not a framework already? Or are you looking for a UI framework? if so, then why not use Bootstrap which works great with meteor. Otherwise, Zurb's Foundation also works well.

Comment: jquery mobile (I used only mobile events) worked well for me in a Meteor app

Comment: Of course Meteor is a framework, guess I should have said mobile UI framework. I Do use bootstrap like I mentioned but it's more of a CSS library with some JS components. BS is great but it lacks a lot of mobile features such as- swipe-events, page transitions and touch friendly components/widgets. I may use BS and JS just for the touch events that I really need. Thanks!